Salesforce Edge Network Recently Implemented in UAT - Broke Our Apex-Based REST Endpoint. Issue Related to "Host" Header Value?
Struggling to troubleshoot...
Our full-sandbox UAT instance was recently upgraded to the "Salesforce Edge Network", resulting in one of our apex-based REST services breaking. This service relies on an AWS middleware to send information from WordPress to our instance (WordPress -> AWS -> Salesforce). For additional context, the integration continues to function as-expected in Production (which has NOT been upgraded to the Salesforce Edge Network).
Interestingly, it appears as though it's related to the "host" header value we set, as the integration works just fine being called within Salesforce itself and by Postman.
We're able to simulate the error and confirm it's related to the "host" header value - as callouts succeed when set to "[DOMAIN]--uat.sandbox.my.salesforce.com" and immediately fail when set to any other value.
While we work with our AWS team, are there any solutions we're able to attempt on the Salesforce platform itself?
Error below:


What is the Host value being set to from AWS? Is it a non-enhanced domain URL potentially? If it is going to be an ongoing issue, you can request that it be disabled by Salesforce Customer Support as per this article

@CallumMacErlich I've added some logging in production and found the host value that's sent via the middleware is "https://[SERVER_NAME_REDACTED].execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/". Interestingly, this host value works just fine (unless we run the same code on our edge-enabled UAT).

Quick update, after a long chat, Salesforce support wasn't able to find a resolution. I've found a strange workaround though: Under Setup > My Domain, the "Redirections" section has a URL. Making an HTTP request to that URL, rather than our my domain URL, allowed me to successfully make requests regardless of a Host header value.
